# Get read write access to windows partitions on internal hard drive

Tags: filesystem, 16.10

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 from an external hard drive and want to read and write to windows partitions on internal hard drive. How can I set the required permissions?

I have tried setting permissions using properties in Nautilus file manager but that doesn't help.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** an issue of file permissions. Changing settings via Nautilus won't help.

Newer Windows (8/8.1/10) use hybrid shutdown instead of regular shutdown. This makes them boot faster since the system is resuming from hibernation. But this creates problems when you try to use the partitions of hibernated windows with Linux.

To be able to access the Windows partitions from Linux, you should properly shutdown Windows.

To do that, open a command prompt windows as administrator, type and press enter

```
shutdown -s -t 00
```

You have to do this every time to need to access Windows partitions from Linux.

To turn the hybrid shutdown off permanently, open a command prompt as administrator, type and press enter

```
powercfg /h off
```

---

Read more about it here - [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)